# How to pass Java method parameter to get correct horizontal alignment for JLabel

Tags: java

I have a simple routine to make labels, but I can't figure out how to pass the correct horizontal alignment as the second argument when I call it.  If I want a label with left, center, right, etc alignments.

This line in my code doesn't resolve correctly. "JLabel label = new JLabel(text, JLabel.con);"

```
final static Color labelBG = new Color(255,240,240);  
final static Color labelFG = new Color(3,25,180);
final static Font labelFont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16);
private JLabel countLabel;

countLabel = makeLabel("Number of Entries:", LEFT);

private JLabel makeLabel(String text, SwingContstants con) {
   JLabel label = new JLabel(text, JLabel.con);
   label.setBackground(labelBG);
   label.setForeground(labelFG);
   label.setFont(labelFont);
   label.setOpaque(true);
   return label;
}
```

Comment: What is " doesn't resolve correctly." ? What is the error message? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: horizontalAlignment

Comment: I have tried changing the different types of the argument from int to SwingConstants to JLabel.

Comment: What is the JLabel constructor that you are trying to match?

Comment: the constructor I am using is (string, horizontalAlignment) so if I have JLabel label = new JLabel("Hi", JLabel.LEFT) that works fine, but I can't get my method to replicate that if I want to make it customizable based on argument passed for RIGHT, CENTER, etc.

Comment: `JLabel.LEFT` is an `int`, so that's the type you should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing Constants are ints.

You should change your code to:

```
final static Color labelBG = new Color(255,240,240);  
final static Color labelFG = new Color(3,25,180);
final static Font labelFont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16);
private JLabel countLabel;

countLabel = makeLabel("Number of Entries:", 2);

private JLabel makeLabel(String text, int con) {
   JLabel label = new JLabel(text, con);
   label.setBackground(labelBG);
   label.setForeground(labelFG);
   label.setFont(labelFont);
   label.setOpaque(true);

return label;

}
```

Comment: that worked, thanks, but just one last thing.  where do i find out which numbers correspond with which alignments.  like 2 = JLabel.LEFT, so which number is JLabel.CENTER?

Comment: nevermind, i found it playing around with the swingconstants javadoc in eclipse under constant field values.  i am all set now, thanks.

Comment: Check here for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing